# JQUERY how to get id name from dynamic div?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've got two  dynamic generated (from PHP file) divs. This divs are like this:

```
<div id="x" class="myclass"></div>
<div id="y" class="myclass"></div>
```

Where X and Y are numbers generated dynamically from a php file. How can I get this id (number) when, for expample, I click on this divs?

I've tried in this way:

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){

alert(this.attr("id"));

});
```

But in this way I get only the first id (the first element of myclasses).

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the ids are different? your code should work from eyeballing it, maybe try changing to this `alert( $(this).attr('id'));`

Comment: Are you trying to get all id´s of elements with class `myclass`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this instead:

```
$('.myclass').live('click', function() {
   alert(this.id); //or alert($(this).attr('id'))); for the jQuery method
});
```

Binding events using the `$.live()` function will bind events to elements that do not yet exists, so when you add new div.myclass elements dynamically they will be bound as well.

---

**Please Note:** `.live()` is now deprecated, use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

```
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the jquery object

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Also, don't use just a number for an ID. I think only HTML5 allows it now.

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/SY3m7/

Answer (score 1):

HTML element ID's starting with numbers are not valid.

So try generating an alphanumeric id which starts with a character like "div-10002".

In either case to get the id of the clicked element try this:

```
$('.myclass').live("click", function(){  
 alert(this.id);  
});
```

or

```
$('.myclass').live("click", function(){  
 alert($(this).attr("id"));  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$('.myclass').click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
   alert(this.id);
});
```

take a look at example click on X and Y

http://jsfiddle.net/BJdLJ/4/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get all the ids which pertains to that class?

try this:

```
$(".myClass").each(function(){alert($(this).attr("id"));});
```

You have to invoke the above in another function.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container").on("Events",$(selector),function(e){
    // this will have jquery reference to the container DOM element hence use event.target to capture the element.
    var id=$(e.target).attr("id");
});
```

JonDoeCA - has given this answer in for a [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576876/jquery-get-id-or-class-from-dynamic-element)
(I couldn't credit his answer hence referring).