# Jquery get id or class from dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, element

Let say I have 5 element from *PHP query* (so it is dynamic)
Illustrated below:

```
element 1 class=element id=id_1
element 2 class=element id=id_2
element 3 class=element id=id_3
element 4 class=element id=id_4
element 5 class=element id=id_5
```

We ussulay use *jquery event* by knowing their *class* or *id*, but in this case, we don't know exactly their *id*.

```
$("#id_3").click(function()
{ 
    //in this case we have known we want to add event when we click id_3
});
```

How to deal with dynamic element from *PHP query*?
For example, how can we know that we click on `element 3` with `id_3`?
What must we fill in `$(????).click();`?
When I use class, how can I know which *id* I reference from the class clicked?

Comment: You can put the tag type...so for instance if your elements are divs you can do `$("div").click()` and then use `this.id` inside the click event to see that the id of that element is...

Answer (score 2):

This was the only way I could get it to work.  For example, if you wanted to get the attribute ID or the value of the element that has been clicked...

```
$("containerElem").on("click", "someElemID", function(evt) {
    var getElemID = $(evt.target).attr("id");
    var getVal = $(evt.target).val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example the elements all have the same class, so you can setup your event handler based on that:

```
$(".element").click(function() {
   // "this" refers to the clicked element
   // this.id will be the id of the clicked element
});
```

Or if these elements are dynamic in the sense of being loaded via Ajax at some point after the initial page load use a delegated event handler:

```
$("somecontainerelement").on("click", ".element", function() {
    // do something with this.id
});
```

Where "somecontainerelement" would ideally be the element that the dynamic elements are added to, but could just be `document`.

Comment: I like this solution. By using `on` he has reduced the number of event handlers bound on your page. This increases the efficiency of your javascript. If you are not familiar with `on` then read up. http://api.jquery.com/on/. =)!

Answer (score 0):

If they all have the same class, then you can use a class selector. Then use `this` to find whatever property you are after.

```
$('.element').click(
     $(this).prop('id');
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a click only then why not add that to the generated html on server side?

Comment: This would violate the concept of trying to separate your presentation layer (html/css) from your execution layer (js). I would not recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`attribute starsWith`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector & [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind events on dynamically created elements.

```
$('body').on('click', '[id^=id]', function(e){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is veryusefull when we work on unknown elements with id or class

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // user this if element is div 
  $('div[id^="id_"]').on('click', function() {  
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });
  // user this if element is input
  $('input[id^="id_"]').on('click', function() {  
    alert(this.id);
  });

});
```