# Get name of HtmlDivElement

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the name of an HtmlDivElement object.

```
<div class=a name=b>... </div>
```

I know it is possible to get the  class name by using the method `object.className()`, but is there a equivalent for the name (I want to get  'b') ?

(sorry about my english, I'm French)

Comment: it's just `element.name`

Comment: @Smashmaster - you mean `element.className` (without `()`). It is a property, not a method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902161/jquery-how-to-get-id-name-from-dynamic-div

Comment: @kennypu: It *would* be, if `div` elements had a `name` attribute. But if you try that with a `div`, you'll get `undefined`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I know it is possible to get the class name by using the method object.className()...

No, it's a property: `object.className`

> ...but is there a equivalent for the name (I want to get 'b') ?

For elements where `name` is a valid attribute, it would be `object.name`. But [`div` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) don't have a `name` attribute. The only valid attributes for `div` elements are the standard [global ones](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes), which don't include `name`.

You can, of course, put any attribute on an element if you really want to, it just makes your HTML invalid. You can retrieve those attributes with `getAttribute`:

```
console.log(object.getAttribute("name"));
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/zunepuxa/1)

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
var name = element.getAttribute('name');
```

And note it's `element.className` not `element.className()`, `element.className` is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

You need this function

```
var name = element.getAttribute("name");
```